# Adding watermark to Image in Python using PIL

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, watermark

I am Trying to Add an Watermark to an Image using an PIL(pillow) by this Algorithm

```
def watermark_image_with_text(filename):
    text = 'Watermark'
    color = 'blue'
    fontfamily = 'arial.ttf'
    image = Image.open(filename).convert('RGBA')
    imageWatermark = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imageWatermark)
    width, height = image.size
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontfamily, int(height / 20))
    textWidth, textHeight = draw.textsize(text, font)
    x = width / 5
    y = height / 6
    draw.text((x, y), text, color, font)
    my_img = Image.alpha_composite(image, imageWatermark)
    my_img.save('water_' + filename.name)
    return 'water_' + filename.name
```

It works Fine for PNG files but it does not apply watermark to Images of another file format such as JPG, JPEG, TIF, etc...
can anybody suggest a Generic method for applying watermark to images of all file formats

- The error is `cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

> cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG

The solution is simple. Convert the image back to RGB mode before saving.

```
my_img.convert('RGB').save('water_' + filename.name)
```

This happens because JPEG is designed for photos. As such, it doesn't support transparency (photos aren't transparent). You have to explicitly throw away the transparency data in order to save a JPEG.